# Does the Windows version of the Wordpress desktop app offers the reusable blocks feature?

Tags: desktop, wordpress, app

I am new to WordPress, and I learned the hosted application features something called reusable blocks. These blocks are content that can be reused, and these are called (or inserted) through the text editor.

I am wondering if the WordPress desktop app, Windows version, offers this feature.

Comment: Why don't you try and see?

Comment: @Ramhound gosh!... I know the lines between reality, truth, and misinformation are becoming blurred, but I seriously think this webpage states there is a Wordpress Desktop app https://apps.wordpress.com/desktop/

Comment: @Ramhound what is the scope of superuser.com?

Comment: @DigitalStreaming You can find the scope of the site in https://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Start by taking a look into the official resources for end users.

Go to https://apps.wordpress.com/d/windows/

[image]

If the menu options are not visible, click the menu button (the hamburguer button)

[image]

Then click in Support

[image]

Then click in Desktop App

[image]

If the available resources doesn't include the details that you are looking for consider to install the app an explore it thoroughly.